# FCM api 'Bad request 400' error

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to implement sending notifications via new FCM api protocols. I went through authenticating requests, I enabled api in google console as well. Now when I send request I'm receiving Bad request 400 error. Response doesn't contain any other information than error code and error message. Even reason field says 'Bad Request'. I'm implementing it with [FCM api docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message).

```
def fcm_test():
    FCM_URL = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/MY_PROJECT_NAME/messages:send"
    my_token = "device-token"

    payload = {
        "massage": {
            "token": my_token,
            "notification": {
                "body": "body",
                "title": "title"
            }
        }
    }

    payload = json.dumps(payload)
    headers = {
        "Authorization": "Bearer {auth_token}".format(auth_token=_get_authentication_token()),
        "Content-Type": "application/json; UTF-8",
    }
    try:
        request = moves.urllib.request.Request(FCM_URL, payload.encode('utf-8'), headers)
        response = moves.urllib.request.urlopen(request, timeout=10)
    except Exception as e:
        pass
    return
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a typo in your payload key, can you try it again with "message" instead of "massage"?

Comment: Unfortunately it helped. Thank you. I was hoping there was some real issue behind it.